# Spark: How to perform prediction using trained data set (MLLIB: SVMWithSGD)

Tags: apache-spark, prediction

I am new to Spark.  I am able to train the DataSet. But not able use the trained data set to make predictions.

Here is the code to train the data which is 1800x4000 matrix.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/ridge-data/myfile.txt")
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(' ')
  LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
}

val firstDataPoint = parsedData.take(1)(0)

// Building the model
val numIterations = 100
val model = SVMWithSGD.train(parsedData, numIterations)
//val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData,numIterations)


val labelAndPreds = parsedData.map { point =>
  val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
  (point.label, prediction)
}
val trainErr = labelAndPreds.filter(r => r._1 != r._2).count.toDouble / parsedData.count
println("Training Error = " + trainErr)
```

Now I load the data to be used to perform the prediction: Data is vector of 1800 values

```
val test = sc.textFile("data/mllib/ridge-data/data.txt")
```

But not sure how to perform prediction using this data. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First load the labeledPoints from the textFile (keep in mind you had to save the RDD with saveAsTextFile):

```
JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> test = MLUtils.loadLabeledPoints(init.context, "hdfs://../test/", 30).toJavaRDD();
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> scoreAndLabels = test.map(
  new Function<LabeledPoint, Tuple2<Object, Object>>() {
    public Tuple2<Object, Object> call(LabeledPoint p) {
      Double score = model.predict(p.features());
      return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(score, p.label());
    }
  }
);
```

Now collect the scores and iterate over them:

```
List<Tuple2<Object, Object>> scores = scoreAndLabels.collect();
    for(Tuple2<Object, Object> score : scores){
    System.out.println(score._1 + " \t" + score._2);
}
```

It is in Java, but maybe you can convert it :)

But the prediction values do not make sense:
-18.841544889249917     0.0
168.32916035523283      1.0
420.67763915879794      1.0
-974.1942589201286      0.0
71.73602841256813       1.0
233.13636224524993      1.0
-1000.5902168199027     0.0
Does anybody know what they mean?